# Best way to implement an async "loadData" method using the MVVM pattern

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, windows-runtime, windows-phone-8.1

I'm trying to understand what is the best approach to use when calling an async method that updates my ViewModel.
Right now, let's say I have something like this:

**View:**

```
private async void NavigationHelper_LoadState(object sender, LoadStateEventArgs e)
{
    //Call my ViewModel method to update the data the UI is bound to          
}
```

**ViewModel:**

```
public async Task loadData()
{
    this.Source = await loadStuffFromDatabaseAsync();
}
```

Now, I'm not sure which one of the following approaches should I use:

**1)** In my LoadState method, use:

```
await Task.Run(async () => { await ViewMode.loadData(); });
```

**2)** Use
    Task.Run
without awaiting the
    loadData
method inside the
    Action
:

```
await Task.Run(() => { ViewModel.loadData(); });
```

**3)** Call my
    loadData
method with:

```
await ViewModel.loadData().ConfigureAwait(false);
```

**4)** Call the
    loadData
method without awaiting it in my
    View class
and use
    Task.Run
inside my loadData method:

**View:**

```
private void NavigationHelper_LoadState(object sender, LoadStateEventArgs e)
{
    ViewModel.loadData();  
}
```

**ViewModel:**

```
public async void loadData()
{
    await Task.Run(async () => 
    {
        this.Source = await loadStuffFromDatabaseAsync();
    });
}
```

What are the main differences between these approaces?

Is one more efficient that the other, and should I pick one in particular?

Thanks for your help! :)

Sergio

Comment: async void methods should be avoided, and you should follow the naming convention of appending Async to all async methods.

Comment: I believe that Reed Cosby has taught us all that all we need now since Asynch support was integrated into base code is two words   Async and Await.  We no longer need to call the Task methods.

Comment: @JohnPeters: That's not true. There might be code that's blocking the UI thread.

Comment: @Fred Yup, exactly :)
Since my loadData method reads stuff from a database and returns a list of classes, it doesn't need to run on the UI thread, and I was wondering which was the best way to make it run on the background thread.

Comment: I don't think any of the code makes sense, here's why...If you are already using Asynch and Await, which you are in the first example of the view model, why would you want to spin off a new thread when a new thread gets spun off anyway?  It doesn't make sense.  loadData is already async.  You already have all you need.

Comment: @JohnPeters No, that "loadDataAsync" is just the name I gave it in the example. In my code I have a method I wrote that does some async stuff without calling Task.Run or anything else, it just uses the await operator. So from what I understood, it should still run on the caller thread. Shouldn't I move the whole thing to the background thread to be sure the UI doesn't lag?

Comment: @PhilipStuyck besides top-level event handlers as in his example

Comment: async void loadData is not an eventhandler in the viewmodel of the last example.

Comment: @Sergio0964, I must have been sleeping yesterday when I read this, my apologies.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should only use `Task.Run` if you have CPU-bound or blocking work that you want to move off the UI thread. That's not the case here, so the direct call (option 3) is the most natural.

Taking them in turn:

```
await Task.Run(async () => { await ViewMode.loadData(); });
```

This option will execute `loadData` on a thread pool thread. This may not work very well, since `loadData` is updating the UI (indirectly by setting a VM property). Even if it does happen to work (i.e., some MVVM frameworks can properly handle updates from background threads in some scenarios), it's probably unnecessary since `loadData` is an asynchronous method.

Furthermore, it adds `async` state machine overhead for no reason.

```
await Task.Run(() => { ViewModel.loadData(); });
```

This option has all the same problems, except it's slightly more efficient since it doesn't have the `async` state machine overhead. But it's still updating VM properties on a background thread and using a background thread unnecessarily.

```
public async void loadData()
```

This one's the worst of all. It inherits the same problems of the others: updating VM properties on a background thread and using an unnecessary background thread. To that it adds the problems of `async void`. One problem is that `NavigationHelper_LoadState` cannot catch any exceptions from `loadData`. Another problem is that `loadData` is not easily testable.

So just use the simple approach and call it directly:

```
await ViewModel.loadData().ConfigureAwait(false);
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer! I just have a doubt: you said I should use Task.Run for CPU-bound or blocking work only: why doesn't loading data from a database count as a blocking work? As it is an IO operation, couldn't that take a long time to complete, and therefore block the calling method that's awaiting that Task?

Comment: The thread is not blocked because it's an asynchronous operation.

Comment: You're right, by "blocking work" you meant some synchronous code to run. Thanks again for your help :)